# communicate with rest services via domino agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino, agent

I need to communicate with an external REST service. Basically I have to 'sync' information between a Notes database and the other system e.g. when user creates a document in Notes a similar 'note' should be created in the other system.

I have received info that describes the service (how to perform crud operations).

I assume the agent should be written in java instead of lotusscript.

Can anyone provide an example for an agent to connect to the service and perform basic post/get calls?

Comment: Some helpful examples for consuming REST service in Java in context of XPages you can find here: http://www.assono.de/blog/d6plinks/IBM-Connect-2014-BP206

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for sample code for a very general requirement. StackOverflow is intended for helping people solve specific problems in software development. The questioner provides no specifics about what REST service he wants to invoke, the nature of his existing application and the data that it is managing, what research he has done, or what he has tried.

Comment: I am not gonna consume REST via an XPage. Initially a Domino agent will scheduled create new notes in a different system.

Comment: i am looking for a basic construction of the domino agent... (open connection with other system, write to it, read response(s)).

Comment: Read page 13 to 23 in BP206.pdf and you have all what you need (including links) to build a Java agent consuming a REST service.

Comment: A description of POST, PUT and DELETE you can find in addition to example GET in BP206.pdf here: https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with